# How to Show Wasserstein Metric is Sum Invariant?

Tags: distance-functions, invariance, wasserstein

A paper I'm trying to understand states that that Wasserstein metric obeys certain properties, which I'd like to prove. This metric is defined for two random variables $U, V$ and $p \in (1, \infty)$ as:

$$d_p(U, V) = \Big( \int_0^1 dw |F_U^{-1}(w) - F_V^{-1}(w)|^p \Big)^{1/p}$$

where $F_U$ and $F_V$ are the cumulative distribution functions of $U, V$. The authors call one property "sum invariance," which states that for random variable $A$ independent from $U$ and $V$,

$$d_p(U+A, V+A) \leq d_p(U, V).$$

How can I prove this?